# Is storing HTML on a DB sane/safe for a blog?

Tags: html, database, blogs

I plan to make a blog-ish (Not enough of a blog to deserve a CMS/Wordpress instance though) platform with a WYSIWYG editor to enable admins to post articles. I have been wondering if storing HTML on the Database (for the article text) is sane and/or safe (I can always sanitize off all traces of script tags) and if there is a better solution to the issue.

Don't get me wrong: I know it works, but i got this burning itch that there has to be a better solution out there which i am not aware of.

Comment: I think there is no problem with that if you handle it properly, also `WordPress` stores `html` in database.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 I thought that as well, just wanted to know if there was another markup that fit the needs of a blog or something liekke that

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You could store it in the file system, but then you lose the advantage of the database (like single backup with your other stuff, or cascading deletes).

You are going to want to sanitize the HTML before you store it, as it may contain XSS. You don't want to accidentally return that in say an admin interface by accident.

In Java, you could use Hibernate Validator's @SafeHtml annotation / JSoup's library to sanitize.

You should also escape the HTML on the server before outputting it, so that no unsafe JavaScript is run in the browser.

Also:

- use HTTP-only session cookies (so that an XSS attack can't use them)
- X-XSS-Protection = 1;mode=block
- X-Content-Security-Policy = default-src 'self'
- Content-Security-Policy = default-src 'self'
- X-WebKit-CSP = default-src 'self'
- use X-Content-Type-Options = nosniff header (I think)

Comment: Thanks, i will adopt these countermeasures